# MarkLogic - node.js - How to require cts for search

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I have the node db connection working okay I think:

```
var marklogic = require('marklogic');
var db = marklogic.createDatabaseClient({ ...
```

And now I want to do cts.search
How do I require cts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. The cts functions are for running queries within the database. Working with the Node.js Client API, you'll use the query builder. There's an example in the [feature introduction](http://developer.marklogic.com/features/node-client-api), with more detail in the [Getting Started tutorial](http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/node-client-api) and the [Node.js Application Developer's Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev).

You may be mixing up the Node.js Client API with [Server-side JavaScript](http://developer.marklogic.com/features/javascript). The former is used to have middle-tier Node.js code interact with MarkLogic. The latter is for writing REST API extensions or transformations that run within the database (and can be called from the Node API).

Comment: This really clears a few things up. I'm just getting started with the node client API.